# Help on understanding deadlock

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock, deadlock-graph

[image: deadlock]

A deadlock issue is encountered when adding column to an existing table, from my attempt to understand the graph, a linked server calling sp_columns_100_rowset is having an update lock on sysschobjs, which is very strange, any idea why is this happening?

Deadlock xml: https://pastebin.com/ssGrYZ7q

Comment: The deadlock seems to involve extended properties which is unusual. Are you specifying extended property values in your DDL to add the column - if not I would check for a trigger

Comment: Hi, the extended property is intended as part of the DDL to add the column

Comment: Same ole, same ole on deadlocks. Look to the complete set of code being used by both processes. Ensure that access to the objects is in the same order in both, not one updating the properties before a select and one after, or whatever it may be.

Comment: The issue is that we haven't been able to identify the actual query on the left, it seems like it is getting metadata from a linked server, no idea why is it having an update lock on sysschobjs in the first place